# How to clean data in attribute table in QGIS 2.18.14?

Tags: qgis, expression, regular-expression, replace

I have a 'name' field with composite name; numbers and words
e.g. "1237, Café"

I managed extract the part number with Field Calculator and make a new field *(see 1)* with this expression

> left(  "Name" , strpos(  "Name"  ,'\s') - 1)

But I can´t find the way to extract the part names - just words!

If I use this

> regexp_replace(  "Name" , '\W', ' ')

Creating a new field result only fields with numbers...*(see 2)*

EDITED: correction; the results with only numbers; if the type is "whole number (integer)"!!

Updating the 'name' field, result the same fields only without ','... e.g. "1234 Café"

[image]

Comment: To get the words only, you could try something like:  regexp_replace( "name",'[\\d,]','')

Answer (score 4):

RESOLVED

Example: "1237, Café"

1. **To extract the number to a new field 'addr_num'**

In the Field Calculator

- New Field: 'addr_num'
- Type: Whole **number** (integer)
- Lenght: 10

Expression:

> left( "Name" , strpos( "Name" ,'\s') - 1)

*[[see post]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241195/extracting-only-number-from-address-in-qgis-attribute-table)*

Result "1237"

2. **To extract the 'name' part to a new field 'new_name'**

In the Field Calculator

- New Field: 'new_name'
- Type: Text (string)
- Lenght: 80

Expression:

> regexp_replace( "name",'[\d,]','')

Result: " Café"

Credit: *@cm1*

But to trim spaces:

> trim(  regexp_replace ( "name",'[\d,]','') )

Result:

"Café"

[REGEX](https://regexr.com/):

\s - whitespace

\d - digit